# Is there a downside to using Google Analytics on my MVC pages?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, google-analytics

I would like to use Google Analytics but I am concerned about adding more script and slowing down the loading of my web page. Is there some way in MVC3 that I can minimize the impact of the additional scripts. Should I really be concerned about additional time to download the analytics JS ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The analytics JS file is tiny and the script should be executed at the very latest moment ideally after the rendering of your page to not impact the user.  I wouldn't worry too much about the perf. as so many sites use it.  just make sure you follow the instructions to adding the tag probably and you should be fine.

[image]

Comment: Is there some way I could perhaps delay loading? Already I use jQuery and a few other scripts on my site. I don't want to slow down pages any more than needed.

Comment: if following the normal instructions, it's loaded async anyway, so it should load 'behind' the display of any content. i've never ever heard or experienced issues in this area in all the years that i've been doing web dev in php or .net.

Comment: the default tag mechanism delays loading until the last minute due to the way it works.  i've included the timings in the answer to illustrate.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, there could be an additional cost for those scripts. No, there is nothing you could do in ASP.NET MVC (or any other technology) to reduce it as you depend on Google. There is no free lunch. And I shouldn't be worried about it, many very high traffic sites (including this one) use it.

Comment: U mean I should not worry about the additional load time or are you saying it's not good to use?

Answer (score 0):

If you're worried about the loading time then [Google offer an async version](http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/tracking/asyncTracking.html), so just fire and forget. It then shouldn't get in the way of loading.

Comment: Beware that the async script execution feature is only available [since IE10+](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_script_async.asp).